# Make a new array with all the similar key values from previous array using .reduce()

Tags: javascript, reduce

How can I turn the array:

```
data = [
{key1: a, key2: 1},
{key1: b, key2: 2},
{key1: c, key2: 3}]
```

into the array:

```
newArray = [1, 2, 3]
```

using reduce?

Comment: please add your try and add why do you want to reduce the array.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to reduce (transform an array into a single element) but you try to map (transform an array into another array)

```js
data = [
 {key1: 'a', key2: 1},
 {key1: 'b', key2: 2},
 {key1: 'c', key2: 3}
]

console.log(data.map(el => el.key2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you really want, but seeing your example if you want to create a new array with the values of particular key in the object with reduce you can do it something like this:

```
const data = [
    {key1: "a", key2: 1},
    {key1: "b", key2: 2},
    {key1: "c", key2: 3}
];

const ans = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    prev.push(curr.key2);
    return prev;
}, []); // start with empty array

// ans: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

But, if you want to separate all the keys in a new set of arrays you can do it something like this:

```
const data = [
    {key1: "a", key2: 1},
    {key1: "b", key2: 2},
    {key1: "c", key2: 3}
];

const ans = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    Object.keys(curr).forEach((key) => {
        if (!prev[key]) {
            prev[key] = [curr[key]];
        } else {
            prev[key].push(curr[key]);
        }
    });
    return prev;
}, {}); // start with empty object

// ans: { key1: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], key2: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

As my recommendation, I prefer using [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is cleaner and faster than `reduce` or `forEach` or `map`

Example of both:

```
// Example 1:
const ans = [];
for (const obj of data) {
    ans.push(obj.key2);
}
// ans: [ 1, 2, 3 ]

// Example 2:
const ans = {};
for (const obj of data) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        if (!ans[key]) {
            ans[key] = [obj[key]];
        } else {
            ans[key].push(obj[key]);
        }
    }
}
// ans: { key1: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], key2: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```